# Display Power Apps Checkbox Control Selected Value in Text label

Tags: button, radio-button, powerapps, selecteditem, textlabel

I have added a four-check box control and set its Text property manually. Till now, it's fine, Now, I want to display the checkbox control selected values on the text label by clicking the button control.
Here, I have used below code:

```
Set(varSelected,If(chk_Finance_1.Value,{Result:"Finance"}))
```

[image]

Please, suggest any solution...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a horizontal blank gallery for your checkboxes. Set the gallery items to:

```
["IT", "HR", "Finance", "Marketing"]
```

Then for your label you can have:

```
Concat( Filter(YourCheckBoxGallery.AllItems, Checkbox1.Value), Checkbox1.Text, ";")
```

Comment: Super, please help mark the answer as Accepted (check-mark below the voting buttons) for the benefit of all.